# How can I host a Django web app on Cpanel out the public_html folder?

Tags: django, cpanel

I am trying to host a Django web application on Cpanel.
However, my hosting service is having a main folder which is called **public_html**. In this folder, there is the index page. My project folder named **myapp** is out of the **public_html** folder. Whenever I run the application, it is showing the content of the **index.html** which is in the **public_html** folder instead of running the home page of my application that should be executed from this main **urls.py** file.
Bellow is the main urls.py content.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView



urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('depenses/', include('depenses.urls', namespace='depenses')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('coupons/', include('coupons.urls', namespace='coupons')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
    # path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='templates/index.html'), name='home'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Again my project is out of the public_html folder.

Please assist me to host my application.

Comment: Here is my domain name: halfastyle.fr

Comment: you may want to check that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior considering the fact that the web service will attempt to serve HTML/PHP files only.
You will need to deploy your Django app through a python interpreter like Apache Passenger or something similar that would handle and serve it.

This can be easily achieved without many configurations and hassles with the Python App feature of CloudLinux.

Therefore, I would suggest you simply find a hosting provider that provides CloudLinux's Python App feature. The deployment process via that feature is with just a few simple clicks.